# JRuby Rails Console hanging on "Switch to inspect mode"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, git-bash, rails-console, jrubyonrails

Within Git Bash on Windows, `jruby -S rails console` hangs after printing the following:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.8)
Switch to inspect mode.
```

When I ctrl+c to exit, I get the following error stack:

```
Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor - channel: org.jruby.util.io.ChannelFD@1eda12b3
gets at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:2233
gets at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb/input-method.rb:61
block in eval_input at C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb.rb:469
...
```

What is "inspect mode", and how does one switch to it? Why doesn't rails console work in Git Bash when it does work in Command Prompt?